# Element Tree parsing for pagination - while loop throws error that if does not

Tags: xml, python-3.x, elementtree

I am parsing some  paginated xml using Element Tree and wish to create a while loop to enable multiple calls. The relevant section of the xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:api="http://details/api">
    <link href="https://myurl/cat?detail=full" rel="first" type="application/atom+xml"/>
    <link href="https://myurl/cat?detail=full&amp;page=2" rel="next" type="application/atom+xml"/>
    <link href="https://myurl/cat?detail=full&amp;page=5" rel="last" type="application/atom+xml"/>
    <link href="https://myurl/cat?detail=full" rel="self" type="application/atom+xml"/>
```

Having made the call, I can then use an `if` statement to make a second call using the value `url` for the next page:

```
#make API call to get string myxml
tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(myxml))
root = tree.getroot()
y = root.findall(".//{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}link")
for elem in y:
    if elem.attrib['rel'] == 'next':
        url = elem.attrib['href']
        #call API using url
         #This code works, and returns a value for url
```

However, this will only call the API once more. I wish to implement a loop which will repeatedly call the next page whenever `link rel = 'next'` i.e. to make as many API calls as there are pages. To do this, I wish to replace the `if` statement with a `while` statement:

```
#make API call to get string myxml
tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(myxml))
root = tree.getroot()
y = root.findall(".//{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}link")
for elem in y:
    while elem.attrib['rel'] == 'next':
        url = elem.attrib['href']
        #call API again using url
        #This code doesn't work, and return an error `KeyError: 'rel'
```

However, doing it this way, I get the following error: `KeyError: 'rel'`. I do not know why this is happening in one case and not the other.

Comment: Is your XML valid? Can you post output of `print(elem.attrib)` ?

Comment: This is just the top section of the full xml

Comment: print(elem.attrib) outputs: {'type': 'application/atom+xml', 'rel': 'next', 'href': 'https://myurl/cat?detail=full&page=2'}

Comment: @mzjn I mean if I enter my code after the API call, it will find rel = next once and make another API call but stop. I wish to then look for rel=next in subsequent calls as part of a loop.

Comment: I think you need to update "elem" variable in the loop

Comment: @Mehmet - can you elaborate please?

Comment: when you set "url" to next page URL, "root, y, elem" variables are still containing previous XML data

Comment: If there is a `link` element that does not have a `rel` attribute, then `elem.attrib['rel']` will result in a KeyError. In the XML fragment that you have shown us, all link elements do have a `rel` attribute.

Comment: Thank you both. I can see the error